# Which databases are recommended to be used as embedded databases?

Tags: database-recommendation, embedded

Which databases are recommended to be used as embedded databases to store data within an application?  The embedded database may or may not synchronize back to a larger system database.

Comment: This question is not automatically bad, but in that form it is. See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A list can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database). I think the overwhelming leader in embedded sql databases is sqlite. Found everywhere!

Comment: I'm gonna go with this is an excellent example of why this question isn't right for the site. Because all we have to do is turn to WP and get the answer. I don't like it.

Answer (score 5):

SQLite is probably the most commonly used one.  It is light weight and has an open license.  SQLite is being used by many embedded systems including [Apple's iPod/iPhone/iTouch line of mobile devices, Google's Android phones, and Airbus aircraft](http://www.sqlite.org/famous.html).

Given this I would probably recommend its use, but I will say that I myself have not used it for an embedded system.

Answer (score 4):

At my previous employer, we sold applications with SQL Server Compact as the embedded database. It has some quirks, but it works reasonably well.

Comment: SQL Server Compact edition is probably the most used embedded database platform out there.  Every Windows installation from Vista up (and probably XP) has at least one program using it, Windows Media Player.  Anyone using the Zune software is also using it.

Comment: This however, makes me think that the question is acceptable, but not with the current wording.